# Layouts of smartgwt are automatically!! adding to rootpanel

Tags: smartgwt

I'm using smartgwt. I have created some Layout objects when I run my app in dev mode all the Layouts are added to my page but I have not added all of them to rootpanel. Is it because of browser doesn't refresh the page or jetty doesn't render? I have cleared the browser cache and made my app clean&build, but the issue isn't solved.

Answer (score 2):

When you call draw(), SmartGWT components render themselves.  You don't need to add them to RootPanel, and in fact you should not do so - draw() is preferred unless some third-party code is forcing you to go through RootPanel.